# On the Ruby on Rails Tutorial Chapter 8 and I'm getting "Failure/Error: fill_in "Password", with: user.password Capybara::ElementNotFound:"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, railstutorial.org

for some reason rspec/factory girls cannot find the email.  I've been playing with this for hours and still cannot get it to work.  I've googled the hell out of it but it just doesn't want to work.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do

  subject { page } 

  describe "sign page" do 
    before { visit signin_path }

    it { should have_content('Sign in') }
    it { should have_title('Sign in') }
    end

  describe "signin" do 
    before { visit signin_path }

  describe "with invalid information" do 
    before { click_button "Sign in" }

    it { should have_title('Sign in') }
    it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid') }
    end

    describe "after visiting another page" do 
      before { click_link "Home" } 
      it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
    end
  end

   describe "with valid information" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before do
        fill_in "Email",    with: user.email.upcase       
        fill_in "Password", with: user.password
        click_button "Sign in"
      end

    it { should have _title(user.name) }
    it { should have_link('Profile', href: user_path(user)) }
    it { should have_link('Sign out',    href: signout_path) }
    it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }
        end
    end
```

Here is the session page code:

```
<% provide(:title, "Sign in") %>
<h1>Sign in</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>

    <p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %></p>
  </div>
</div>


Controller Code: class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])      
  end
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

And the error that is coming up is this:

```
1) Authentication with valid information
     Failure/Error: fill_in "Email",    with: user.email.upcase
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find field "Email"
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:33:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error in the same place. Just add `visit signin_path` above `fill_in "Email",    with: user.email.upcase`. As I understand correctly, creating Factory user doesn't mean that you automaticaly direct to signin page.

Or you can add the line to your Factory file, after creating user.

Answer (score 1):

Inspect the generated html using for example Firebug, and check the input id.
Then use the input ID with fill_in, in my case is "user_email" and "user_password"

```
   describe "with valid information" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before do
        fill_in "user_email",    with: user.email.upcase       
        fill_in "user_password", with: user.password
        click_button "Sign in"
      end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
fill_in "Email" to
fill_in "email"
```

According to your email text_field.

Incase if you've login_email as a text field , inspect it in the console and see whether it is email or login_email. And now

```
 fill_in "login_email"
```